# If I vote against reopening a question and later edit it, is my earlier negative vote canceled?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

I got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75052613/jdbc-queryforlist-column-use-as-create-alias-invalid) in the review queue for reopen votes. I initially found it unclear so I voted to leave it closed; but later I read it again and finally understood what the author meant. I [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75052613/3) the question to rephrase it so it’s hopefully easier to understand for others.
Is it equivalent to a -1 vote followed by a +1 vote, or is my -1 vote canceled?

Comment: As someone with 3k+ rep, why not just cast a reopen vote? The question, according to the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75052613/timeline) is still in the review queue at this time.

Comment: Editing the question has no effect on your vote against reopening it. However, you can independently cast a vote to reopen the question.

Comment: Note, as well, that someone voting in the review to keep the question closed doesn't reduce the number of reopen votes on it. Unlike a post's score, which can be both reduced and go below 0, the reopen votes can only go up. If, for example, someone votes to reopen in the review queue, another user votes to reopen by viewing the question, and then (finally) a user in the review queue votes for the question to remain closed, the number of reopen votes on the question is still 2, not 1, and it will still only take 1 more reopen vote for the qusetion to be reopened.

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood the "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening." checkbox when editing the question; I thought it was a reopen vote but it’s not.

Comment: Note: this question is quite confusing as it mixes terminology of up/down-votes (+1/-1) vs re-open votes (and possibly vs voting to "keep closed"). Consider editing to update +1/-1/"negative vote" wording.

Comment: Wait, if the checkbox isn't a reopen vote, what *is* it for?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It sends it to the Reopen Votes review queue: "*By submitting an edit for review, the editor agrees that their edit attempts to resolve the question’s close reason(s) and should be considered for reopening in the Reopen votes queue.*" - [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The question reflects my own confusion on the matter so I’m not sure how to best edit it :)

Comment: @zcoop98 if you have enough rep to vote to reopen a question, shouldn’t it send it to review AND cast a reopen vote?

Comment: That would be a [[tag:feature-request]], @bfontaine (I can't see that such a request exists from a quick search).

Comment: Making the checkbox also cast a reopen vote would be nasty for two reasons: 1) what happens if the user already ran out of reopen votes (can they still submit their edit?), and 2) what happens if a user edits a question that is currently under review (when the checkbox is already ticked(!) and cannot be unticked). Especially case 2 would be nasty if that would cast a reopen vote. I have a bit of edit OCD, which means that if I review, I'll likely edit things even if I don't want to cast a reopen vote (especially for upvoted questions or duplicates, which will not be cleaned up by the roomba).

Comment: @Lamu thanks, I submitted [it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422659/if-i-have-sufficient-rep-i-should-be-able-to-edit-a-closed-question-and-cast-a).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I think I addressed your concerns in the feature request. (I can only mention one user per comment)