# If I have sufficient rep, I should be able to edit a closed question and cast a reopen vote at the same time

Tags: feature-request, edits, vote-to-reopen

This feature request comes from [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422644/735926), especially [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422644/if-i-vote-against-reopening-a-question-and-later-edit-it-is-my-earlier-negative?noredirect=1#comment943023_422644).

When I edit a closed question, there’s a checkbox below the edit area that reads:

> This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening.

Checking it adds the question to the "Reopen votes" review queue. However, it does *not* cast a reopen vote, which is IMHO confusing given the wording of the checkbox. I think it should cast a reopen vote if I have enough rep.

If I don’t have enough rep or have exhausted my daily reopen votes, it should send it in the review queue anyway like it does right now.

[@MarkRotteveel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel) made [two objections](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422644/if-i-vote-against-reopening-a-question-and-later-edit-it-is-my-earlier-negative?noredirect=1#comment943026_422644) to this feature:

> 1. what happens if the user already ran out of reopen votes (can they still submit their edit?)

They can submit their edit and the question goes in the review queue (same behavior as now).

> 2. what happens if a user edits a question that is currently under review (when the checkbox is already ticked(!) and cannot be unticked). [That] would be nasty if that would cast a reopen vote. I have a bit of edit OCD, which means that if I review, I'll likely edit things even if I don't want to cast a reopen vote (especially for upvoted questions or duplicates, which will not be cleaned up by the roomba).

Right now, I don’t think it makes sense to have this checkbox when you review a question. The question is already in the review queue, so why have a "checkbox" (that you cannot uncheck) to send it… to that same review queue? Am I missing [something](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Chesterton%27s_fence)?

It should instead be checked by default and cast a reopen vote when you submit your edit. You should be able to uncheck it to edit a question without casting a vote, like what @MarkRotteveel does. The checkbox should not appear if you don’t have enough rep to cast a vote. It should be greyed-out if you have enough rep but have exhausted your votes for today.

Comment: I strongly disagree. That checkbox should definitely *not* be checked by default when editing. By default, editing should *not* cast a reopen vote or push the question into the reopen queue. The default action for a first edit after closure *used to be* to push the question into the reopen queue. That default caused a lot of problems. Pushing it into the reopen queue, through an edit that *does* resolve the issues or through casting a reopen vote, should be an *active choice*, not be the default action.

Comment: If you're talking about *only* after you've begun the "Edit and reopen" action in the reopen queue, then please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I think 2. pretty much shoots down this suggestion. It means the benefit applies only under very narrow conditions (for the *first* edit making it re-openable) and isn't consistent with the checkbox (which *already* serves as *more* than applying your own re-open vote).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "isn't consistent with the checkbox (which already serves as more than applying your own re-open vote" - it does something that you might see as more important, but it doesn't actually apply that vote, to my understanding. So it can't strictly be considered "serving as more than". I don't think the feature request is about adding a *new* UI widget, but about *making that checkbox click have additional semantics*.

Comment: I agree with other commenters that the checkbox should not be checked by default, but otherwise I see no issue with the proposal as I understand it. But I think there is a lot of mutual confusion over both the proposal and the existing state of affairs - **including on my own part** - so I tried to address this with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now, I don’t think it makes sense to have this checkbox when you review a question. The question is already in the review queue, so why have a "checkbox" (that you cannot uncheck) to send it… to that same review queue?

I believe you are, although I think others have misunderstood you somewhat too. On the other hand, I'm not sure I understand the system itself.

I'm going to try to talk through this, according to my own understanding, and see if we can figure it out together. So, to my understanding:

---

If you don't check the box, then *nothing happens* except that the post is edited. It is very possible to wish to edit a closed post while thinking it should remain closed. For example:

- The post is a duplicate, but it can be given a better title or otherwise polished to make it more clear that it is a duplicate.
- The post is both poorly written *and* missing some sort of debugging detail; the editor can remove noise and fix grammar, but not add missing information (since only the OP *has* that information).

By checking the box, the question is put into a review queue. This improves visibility for *other people* to cast open votes. It *does not*, however, cast your own reopen vote.

You seem to be imagining only the situation in which you come across a post by browsing the list, and edit a closed question that has just been closed. Mark, however, seems to be imagining the situation in which one comes across a closed post *from* that review queue. In this case, the "This edit resolves the problem" checkbox won't be available, since the question is already queued, and people should not have the option to unqueue it.

The specific objection is: people who then edit the question from the queue, should not automatically vote to reopen it.

However, I don't think you had that in mind. My understanding is that you want a simple UI streamlining, whereby consciously *choosing to put something into* the review queue also casts that vote.

My difficulty with participating in the discussion is that *I do not use the queue*, so I don't understand the interface that is actually presented already. In particular:

1. When editing from the queue, does the UI show a checkbox for this question, which cannot be unchecked? Or was this a more metaphorical description on Mark's part of the fact that the question is queued and will stay queued (i.e., no checkbox is shown in the UI at all)?
2. What if the question is in the queue already, but someone else edits it directly from the question page? Is the checkbox shown, as it stands? I assume it is still shown, because I can't recall it *not* being shown to me when I edited a question directly from the page, and presumably sometimes those questions were already in the queue.
3. On the other hand, I could have sworn that editing the post *as the OP* and checking the box automatically casts the first reopen vote. So presumably the feature is at least possible on a technical level.

Comment: The behavior is the same as from the post and the review: the checkbox is always shown on edit, and is always checked if it's already on the queue. Probably to simplify the logic.

Comment: "My understanding is that […]" -> Yes. The simplest way to fix my issue would be to reword the checkbox label. As it is right now, I don’t get why you would check "this edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening" but not cast a reopen vote. It‘s like "I’m in favor of this but I don’t vote for it".